# Find the number of $(m+n)$ digit binary sequences with $m$ $0$'s and $n$ $1$'s such that no two $1$'s are adjacent

Tags: combinatorics

A $k$-digit binary sequence is a word of length $k$ in the alphabet $\{0, 1\}$. Let $n\le m+1$, find the number of $(m+n)$ digit binary sequences with $m$ $0$'s and $n$ $1$'s such that no two $1$'s are adjacent.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! Could you tell us a little bit about the context of the problem, what you've tried so far, and where you're getting stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If you have such a sequence then you can delete the zero that is inmediately left of each one (except for the first one). This can yield any $m+1$ binary sequence with $n$ ones. Moreover this association is bijective. So the answer is $\binom{m+1}{n}$.

Comment: This takes a bit of thought.  The deletion does not occur for the first $1$, whether or not it is the first character in the string.  That is how you get a consistent length of the string with the zeros deleted. +1